# OneNote in Document Library saved under /lists/

Tags: document-library, sync, onenote

I am facing issues when saving a OneNote file in a document library.

In detail I have a document library saved under `/lists/<DocumentLibName>` and I want to use this library to sync OneNote files.

If I am creating a new OneNote File with OneNote 2010 and providing the save location as path of document library, it creates a folder but is not able to sync OneNote files.

If I am trying to open a OneNote file from the Library I cannot see any files while browsing with the OneNote Open Window and if I am giving OneNote the whole path to the file it tries to open but afterwards it cannot sync anything.

Is this causing because document library is saved under Lists? If I am using e.g. the default Documents library from the Team Site template everything works correctly ...

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you are trying to save your OneNote files to a list and not a document library. Normally when you create a Custom list or Announcement list, SharePoint automatically creates it under '/Lists/' to indicate it is a list to the user.

On the other hand when you create a document library it is never under '/Lists/' path unless you have a site named as "Lists' containing that document library, example: http://mySpSite/Lists/myDocLib. (Here mySpSite is root site and Lists is a sub-site). You can check and confirm on this by looking into your own lists and library paths.

As you mentioned in your last statement that when you use "default Documents library from the Team Site template everything works correctly..." this is because you are using the correct content type i.e. a document library for saving your OneNote files.

If you are facing Fehlercode: 0xE000076D error while opening OneNote file then peform below steps unless your issue is resolved:

- Create a new document library and associate OneNote as the default content type template to it and then do your saving and opening of OneNote files.
- Check if Versioning is enabled on your document library if yes then disable it and try again.
- Clear your OneNote cache.

Comment: In this case it is a Visual Studio Solution which creates a custom Document Library under `/Lists/`. Working with other files and Office Programs Word works like a charm but OneNote is not playing with us...

Comment: Try saving your local OneNote file to any SharePoint document library manually and check if file is synced. The problem here seems to be the path '/Lists/'.

Comment: for the first try I moved the default "Documents" Library to `/Lists/` and surprisingly everything still works. (I can create, open and sync the onenote file in this document library) Another thing which is really strange is that I cannot see any files in the open dialog of onenote while trying to open the custom document library. If I am trying to open the uploaded file to the custom list I get the following error code including a message that there was an error during the communication with the webserver: ` (Fehlercode: 0xE000076D)`

Comment: i have edited my answer pls check